Select City where first letter starts with a vowel
I'm doing some coding challenge.
"Query the list of CITY names starting with vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, or u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates."
I solved the challenge with this query:
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE (city LIKE 'a%')
    OR (city LIKE 'e%')
    OR (city LIKE 'i%')
    OR (city LIKE 'o%')
    OR (city LIKE 'u%');

I assume there is a way of doing so without multiple OR statements
OR is it?
I have done some searching and it seemes it all required different/extra libraries.

... where station regexp "^[AEIOU]"

@Charlieface not true.

Yes, there is::
select distinct city
from station where left (station, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

You get the first character via left and then check whether it is among the letters you search for.

@Charlieface one can also do REGEXP "^[aeiou]", not sure about the efficiency though.

@Charlieface why do you say that?  OR-d conditions are going to be much slower.

@ysth Because left(station, 1) in can't use indexes anyway due to the function usage. In SQL Server and Postgres I can tell you an OR is no worse than using left. At the least there is always a chance MySQL could implement the OR as an Index Union. To get an Index Union manually you could do SELECT ... WHERE station LIKe 'a%' UNION SELECT ... WHERE station LIKE 'b%' UNION ... which should have got the best plan, although I agree that MySQL doesn't do this well becaus eit has no Merge Join/Union operator like the others do https://dbfiddle.uk/rESizID0

@Charlieface Using UNION ALL rather than UNION will be much faster, see https://dbfiddle.uk/5xUG7B-Y

@JonasMetzler True, although depending on the query that might get duplicate results (not this case)

@Charlieface mysql will not use or'd conditions for index lookup
